# how can i sort columns descending in excel using vb6

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

i'm developing a application that load data from DB to an excel sheet.
And in one of these columns, I need to sort in a  DESCENDING form.
But I just cant do this, because all the time this give me errors...
In the ascending form (default) I can do it and it passes without any trouble, but when I try to put the parameter of the descending, this don't pass it.

EDIT*
First, declarations and constants:

```
Dim obj_excel As Object
Set obj_excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oSheet As Object ' Worksheet
Dim oChart As Object ' To declare chart Excel

obj_excel.Workbooks.Add 'add a workbook to the app
obj_excel.Sheets(w_Plan1).Select
obj_excel.Sheets("Folha2").Name = "Provider"

obj_excel.cells(1, w_coluna).Font.Bold = True

'header
obj_excel.cells(1, w_coluna).Font.Size = 10
obj_excel.cells(1, w_coluna).Value = "OF"
obj_excel.cells(1, w_coluna).HorizontalAlignment = -4108

'Assigning values to one cell
obj_excel.cells(w_linha, 2).Font.Bold = False
obj_excel.cells(w_linha, 2).Font.Size = 10
obj_excel.cells(w_linha, 2).Value = obj_cmpcil0.H_cdforneced1
obj_excel.cells(w_linha, 2).HorizontalAlignment = -4108
...
.....
......
'Creating a chart
Set oSheet = obj_excel.worksheets.Item(2)
Set oChart = oSheet.ChartObjects.Add(250, 10, 660, 450).Chart
oChart.SetSourceData Source:=oSheet.Range(w_Plan2 & "!$A$1:$C$11")
```

Of course there is a lot more code... but I just put here fragments of code and the chart built like example to you see how my code is organized and declared..

*FINISH EDIT

the ascending form that my code works:

```
    obj_excel.Sheets(2).Range("A2:C25").Sort _
        key1:=obj_excel.Sheets(2).Columns("C")
```

the form that I tryng to add the descending Parameter:

```
obj_excel.Sheets(2).Range("A2:C25").Sort _
        key1:=obj_excel.Sheets(2).Columns("C") _
        Order1:=xlDescending, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

the parameters of method sort, isnt it all optional?

Comment: `OrderCustom:=1` is what is causing the issue. Get rid of it and it should run fine

Comment: Cor_Blimey i put it off but the problem still the same

Comment: ah, apologies - that was just something that looked odd at first glance.

Comment: 2 random ideas (i can't currently play around with your code to try and work it out, hence the idea above that didn't work). 1) using C2:C25 for the key1 or 2) using the Worksheet.Sort object instead of the Range.Sort method.

Comment: Ohh.. i cant believe, this doesnt work for me :( the problem still the same.. I tried the two ways.. thanks for helping.. if you can continuing.

Comment: Are you really using VB6? If Yes, did you define values for Excel constants like `xlDescending` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams what do you mean? all that i did about the values and parameters are in the code there.. i didnt declare and define any values previously

Comment: Im using vb6! i just want to sort an column descending... anyone ever done this???

Comment: VB6 is not the same as VBA - just wanted to be sure.  When running VBA in Excel, xlDescending is a constant defined as part of the Excel library, so you can use it without defining it.  However, when automating Excel from VB6, you would need to define these constants, or use their numerical values instead (which you can determine using the Object Browser in Excel)

Comment: @TimWilliams hmm.. ok understood... so can you give me a example to define these constants? i need to create and define the objects and constants right? its funny cause i did a lot of automations in this app, like the instances, and all worked very well... Just this parameter is giving me error.

Comment: Can you expand your code a little? Eg show some declarations and how you're getting reference to Excel?

Comment: @TimWilliams yeah.. I posted it now.. please can you still helping me?

Comment: Either define the constants you're using in your code e.g. `Const xlDescending = 2` or replace them with their actual numeric values.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry? i didnt understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using actual values instead of Excel-defined `xlXXXX`constants:

```
With obj_excel.Sheets(2)
    .Range("A2:C25").Sort key1:=.Columns("C"), _
                    Order1:=2, _
                    OrderCustom:=1, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    Orientation:=1, _
                    DataOption1:=0

End With
```

Comment: ohhh!! thank you so much, it worked for me finally!! thanksss